# Public Function Format into Public Shared Function Format

Tags: .net, vb.net, function

While working on a simple project and typing Format, the normal `Public Function Format` turned into `Public Shared Function Format`.

The former which only requires *2 parameters* is I have successfully used with a form and when I'm going to use Format in another form, the one that is displaying in IntelliSense is the latter which requires *3 parameters*.

I haven't touch any settings in my forms or coded anything wrong. What should I do?

Comment: The title of your question mislead me completely. You should highlight the exact problem ("Format" function), rather than Public Function vs. Public Shared Function. I wrote an answer explaining the differences Shared/non-Shared. If you do have problems to differentiate both ideas, let me know and I can undelete my answer; otherwise, please correct the title (the "shared" tag does not seem to have a real point either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Problem:***

The `Public Shared Function Format` with two parameters is part of `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. I guess you have imported both:

- a namespace that contains a method named *Format*,
- the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

So, you have a *conflict* and your editor is referencing the wrong one.

***Solution:***

I am not sure to understand which one you want to use:

1. To use the  `Microsoft.VisualBasic` version and make sure you
   reference the correct method, replace:

   ```
   Format(...,...)
   ```

   With:

   ```
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Format(...,...).
   ```
2. To prevent using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` version, try to remove the
   import of `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace (in the form or in the
   project properties).
   Or if the reference is required and you don't want remove it, try to change:

   ```
   Format(...,..,...)
   ```

   With:

   ```
   YourClassName.Format(...,...,...).
   ```

Comment: the only imports that I have is System.Data.OleDB and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. I want to use the normal Format with only 2 parameters. I don't know what really caused it and I just switched to .toString.

Comment: @hajime_saitou Check in the project properties if you have the reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` imported (checked), it's possible that the namespace is imported by default (by default it is, unless I'm wrong) or see edit for a second solution.

Comment: The 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' is default checked. I'll try your suggestions the next time I'll work on the project.

Comment: Tried 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Format' and it works. It's the one that I want to use.

Comment: @hajime_saitou So you need to follow the first solution (write `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Format()` instead of `Format()`. What is the other *Format* class what you don't want to use?

Comment: The _Public Shared Function Format(...,....,...)_ which requires 3 parameters and it is not the usual format that I always used to format strings.

Comment: @hajime_saitou It seems you have imported another class that contains a method named *Format* and that causes trouble. What is this method? (right click > Go to definition)

Comment: The one that causes trouble is under 'System.Enum'

Comment: @hajime_saitou: So remove the import of `System.Enum`?

Comment: I didn't import System.Enum. Looked at my references and there's no System.Enum there. Maybe it is just a bug in VS2012.

Comment: @hajime_saitou I can't say, I'm on VS2010. I will update my answer and will let you know in case I find something else.

Answer (score 2):

An other solution when using names in use by VB or even .NET is to use braces:

```
Public Class Something

     Friend Sub [Format] ()
     ...
     Friend Property [Image] As Bitmap
     ...
```

Of course, you can also tweak your names `FormatThing`, `PicImage`, `Img` etc